# Building Xcode Project Using GNUstep Makefile Does Not Open Application Window, buildtool Can't Find English.lproj

Tags: xcode, gnustep

I completed the [CurrencyConverter example](http://web.archive.org/web/20041018095334/http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000863) using Xcode 2.5 on Mac OS X Tiger 10.4.11, which I called CurrencyConverter2 since it was my second attempt.  Since I've read that GNUstep is compatible with the Mac OS X Tiger version of Cocoa, I wanted to try building this Xcode project in GNUstep, which I am interested in learning.

I was able to install GNUstep on a VM running FreeBSD 12.0.  I created a Makefile called GNUmakefile.  Here are the contents of GNUmakefile:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

APP_NAME = CurrencyConverter2
CurrencyConverter2_OBJC_FILES = main.m ConverterController.m Converter.m
CurrencyConverter2_RESOURCE_FILES = Info.plist English.lproj/MainMenu.nib

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/application.make
```

When building the program using gmake, it appears that everything was built correctly:

```
This is gnustep-make 2.7.0. Type 'gmake print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
Running in gnustep-make version 2 strict mode.
Making all for app CurrencyConverter2...
Creating CurrencyConverter2.app/....
gmake[3]: Warning: File 'main.m' has modification time 21869 s in the future
 Compiling file main.m ...
 Compiling file ConverterController.m ...
 Compiling file Converter.m ...
 Linking app CurrencyConverter2 ...
gmake[3]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
 Creating CurrencyConverter2.app/Resources...
 Creating stamp file...
 Creating CurrencyConverter2.app/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist...
 Creating CurrencyConverter2.app/Resources/CurrencyConverter2.desktop...
 Copying resources into the app wrapper...
```

However, when I try to open CurrencyConverter2.app, the main window does not show up at all.

My hunch is that for some reason my Makefile is not recognizing English.lproj/MainMenu.nib.

I also tried using a tool called buildtool that is able to build Xcode projects using GNUstep, but it complained that it couldn't find English.lproj even though it is in the directory that I ran buildtool.

Comment: GNUstep [**_aims_**](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/User_FAQ#Is_GNUstep_following_changes_to_OpenStep_and_Mac_OS_X.3F) for compatibility. Not sure if really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting a Mac app to GNUstep, you need to make a GNUstep-specific Info-plist template that roughly mirrors Info.plist (which is Mac-only).

At build time, the Info-plist template is used to generate two files: Info-gnustep.plist, and the app's .desktop ([freedesktop.org desktop entry](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en)) file.

Info-gnustep.plist contains Info entries used at loadtime/runtime, such as the name of the principal class, the main-menu nibfile to load, etc.

The app's .desktop file contains Info entries used for registering the app with the desktop-environment/file-browser, such as the app's desktop-menu category, the executable path, supported MIME types, etc. (Note: 'make install' currently doesn't register a GNUstep app with the desktop environment; In order for an installed GNUStep app to appear in the desktop menus, its .desktop file - found in its Resources folder - must be manually registered using the ['desktop-file-install' command-line tool](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-desktop-file-install/).)

The Info-plist template should be named, "{APP_NAME}Info.plist", and can contain a standard XML-format plist, or a simple text-list format:

```
{
   {KEY1} = {VALUE1};
   {KEY2} = {VALUE2};
   ...
}
```

For CurrencyConverter2, create a textfile named "CurrencyConverter2Info.plist" in the same directory as the Makefile, with the contents:

```
{
    ApplicationName = CurrencyConverter2;
    FreeDesktopCategories = ("Utility", "X-GNUstep");
    NSExecutable = "CurrencyConverter2";
    NSMainNibFile = "MainMenu.nib";
    NSPrincipalClass = NSApplication;
    NSRole = Application;
}
```

GNUstep-make will automatically find CurrencyConverter2Info.plist, so it doesn't need an entry in the Makefile.

---

Unrelated to the Info-plist template issue, you can also make these changes to your Makefile:

- Info.plist is Mac-only, so it can be removed from
  CurrencyConverter2_RESOURCE_FILES
- MainMenu.nib can be specified as a localized resource (so it no longer needs English.lproj in its pathname) by removing it from CurrencyConverter2_RESOURCE_FILES and adding these two lines to your Makefile:

  CurrencyConverter2_LOCALIZED_RESOURCE_FILES = MainMenu.nib
  CurrencyConverter2_LANGUAGES = English